# Weird spaces in latex while using \section and \subsection

Tags: page-breaking, white-space

I have this very weird behave  with latex, by adding \subsection or \section it always gives me a huge blank space between 2 questions without adding any \new...
Here pictures :

Image 1:

[image] :

VS image 2 :

[image]

As you can see when I add some text in Question 19 for instance or question below, I had this huge space, it's the first time that I see this weird thing happening... (if you write many questions
then you will automatically see that there are a lot of spaces...)

Here is my code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.2cm,vmargin=3cm,headheight=65pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{lastpage}

% References
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref} % put here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{csquotes}

\colorlet{punct}{red!60!black}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
\definecolor{delim}{RGB}{20,105,176}
\colorlet{numb}{magenta!60!black}

%HEADER <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<,
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhead[C]{Workshop}
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[scale=0.07]{images/im1.png}}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[scale=0.17]{images/im2.png}}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[L]{Workshop, 2022-2023}
\fancyfoot[R]{\textbf{\thepage /\pageref{LastPage}}}  
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  showstringspaces=false,
  commentstyle=\color{red},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
  \begin{sffamily}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{images/im1.png}\hfill
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{images/im2.png}
    \vspace{3cm} 

    \HRule \\[0.4cm]
    { \huge \bfseries Attacks \\[0.4cm] }
    \HRule \\[1cm]   
    
\vspace{8cm}

    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
      \begin{flushleft} \large
        \emph{\textbf{Student :}}\\ 
        \textsc{Name }\\
      \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
    ~
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{flushright} \large
        \emph{\textbf{Teacher :}}\\
        \textsc{Name}\\
      \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}
    \vfill
    
    % Bottom of the page
    \vspace{1cm}
    {\large 2022-2023}

  \end{center}
  \end{sffamily}
\end{titlepage}


\tableofcontents
\section{Part1}
\subsection{Question 1 : }
blabla
\subsection{Question 2 :}
blablabla
\subsection{Question 3 : }
\subsection{Question 4 : }
\subsection{Question 7 : }
\subsection{Question 12 :}
\section{Part2}
\subsection{Question 15 : }
\subsection{Question 16 :} 
\subsection{Question 17 :}
\subsection{Question 18 :}
\subsection{Question 19 :}
text

\end{document}
```

Comment: you have posted a lot of code but mostly unrelated to your issue and if I run it and scroll past the missing images it makes no output pdf. Please  edit the example so it shows the problem. Do not use long sequences of `\subsection` with no text as latex will not break a page between headings

Comment: Are you trying to do a nested  `enumerate` environments? It is unclear to me, but in this case,  \section and \subsection are  the very wrong way.  These commands are only to make the titles of sections of text and put them also in a table of contents, so they have some space before and after the title to highlight  it from the plain text.